# Missing arguments when calling method

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, double

I have this to method, the first one is to calculate the individuals BMI, and the second one is to select the individuals with a normal BMI.

```
static double BMI(TreatedPerson tp) {

    double wei = tp.weight;
    double hei = (tp.height);
    double heim = hei/100;
    double bmindex = wei / (heim * heim);

   return bmindex;
}



static void normalBMI(TreatedPerson tp,double bmindex) {
    double valami = bmindex;
   if (valami > 18.5 && valami < 24.99){
       System.out.println("Normális BMI érték");
   }
}
```

My issue is when I call the method and they are merged into one, instead of seperated, they work this way:

```
   static void outputTreatedPerson(ArrayList<TreatedPerson> treatedpeople) {
        for (TreatedPerson tp : treatedpeople) {
            System.out.println(tp);
            normalBMI(tp);
        }
    }
```

But when I seperate the two methods, I don't know what the arguments should be. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your call to

```
normalBMI
```

in the loop of treated people is missing the BMI parameter.

Maybe you could consider adding a bmi member to the TreatedPerson object

```
public class TreatedPerson {

    // your original class
    private double bmiIndex;

    // getter and setter methods for bmiIndex here
}
```

and then in your first method, BMI(TreatedPerson tp) you could have it void like so

```
public static double BMI(TreatedPerson tp) {

    double wei = tp.weight;
    double hei = (tp.height);
    double heim = hei/100;
    double bmindex = wei / (heim * heim);

    tp.setBMIndex(bmindex);
}
```

this way in your second method (normalBMI) you already have all the info you need and that method can become

```
static void normalBMI(TreatedPerson tp) {
    double valami = tp.getBMIndex();
    if (valami > 18.5 && valami < 24.99){
        System.out.println("Normális BMI érték");
    }
}
```